Movie / TV show where main character has a metallic skull
From a childhood memory:
Format/Look
Movie or TV show. I remember it looking "old", but it was in colour. In my memory, orange/brown colours dominate, so it looked 1970s or earlier. I saw it on German terrestrial TV in the early 1990s.
What I remember from the plot
A male character has (had?) his skull/face replaced by metal. I think this was due to an accident that he suffered. The look of youtube's  Captain Disillusion reminds me a bit of the movie in question.
Another character (maybe the antagonist) has done the same procedure to himself without having suffered an accident. This is done for some evil/selfish purpose - possibly to impersonate the first character or gaining some advantage from having a metallic skull.  I think, the beginning of the procedure is shown, when someone makes a small incision on his face. When the transformation of this second character is revealed, a female character reacts to it with surprise / shock.
One or both of the metallic faces is revealed by unravelling bandages.

Do you know the setting of the movie. Was it is Space, a Apocalyptic Wasteland, Modern Day. Do you remember if the video in English? Or German? Or another language?

Even though the actual movie has been found: modern day to near future. For further details: The whole movie is available on YouTube.

Another possibility is the 1974 movie Who?. Per the Wiki article:

An enigmatic individual with a metal face is returned from East Germany and claims to be Lucas Martino, an American scientist who was working on a top-secret project but was severely injured and scarred in a car crash. American authorities hold him in custody while they try to establish whether the man is the real Martino or an impostor looking for secret information about the ultimate rocket project developed in the West.

This review includes this image of the metal face:


An excellent movie IMHO, that's probably not as well known as it should be, due to its oddity and genre-bending.  It's a combination of low-key (and low-budget) sci-fi and spy thriller that (like all good thrillers) keeps you guessing all the way through, and (like all good sci-fi) asks profound questions: about identity and what it means to be human.  Adaptation of the 1958 novel by Algis Budrys.

Yes. I saw part of it once, during lunch break when I worked in a resort kitchen in the 1980s.  I should try to see the whole thing some time

The series is probably The Six Million Dollar Man about an astronaut who was seriously injured and rebuilt with enhanced metal/electronic parts, which aired from 1973 through 1978.
In the couse of the series, he met other enhanced people, and robot duplicates. You're probably thinking of "Day of the Robot" - when the robot is fought, his face comes off, so it looks like this

Thanks for the answer, but that's not it. I remember distinctly the silver colour of the face. The look resembled youtube's Captain Disillusion a bit. I'll edit the main question to clarify this.

Did the links go wrong? Instead of a face I see Amazon, then Face instead of Amazon.

Yeah the link went wrong somehow. I'll have to figure that out

Now fixed I hope
